# Catch you later

Tags: idiomatic-language

If I call someone on the phone and he picks up and says that he doesn't have time to talk right now, can I say:

*Okay. I'll just catch you later.*

To mean that I'll just call him again later where he hopefully has time to talk

?

Comment: You could say that, or 'I'll try again later."

Comment: Yes, you can: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/catch-you-later